# How can i hide image or button if there is no history onclick="history.go(-1);

Tags: javascript

I use two navigation button to `Go Back` and `Go Previous` but how to hide if there no Previous or Back History

```
<img style="width: 150px;" onclick="history.go(-1);" src="go-back-button2.png"/>

<img style="width: 150px;" onclick="history.go(+1);" src="go-back-button1.png"/>
```

Comment: Something like `  if no-history { IMG.display = none }; ` the question is finding out what your no-history would be.

Comment: no, you cannot put this inside of onclick. What happens in `onclick` remains in `onclick`. You need to decide whether to show the element or not on DOM load / rendering

Answer (score 0):

Detect if there is only a single item and then hide or gray out the element:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <img id="back" style="width: 150px;" onclick="history.go(-1);" src="go-back-button2.png"/>

<img style="width: 150px;" onclick="history.go(+1);" src="go-back-button1.png"/>
<script>
    if(history.length===1){
    document.getElementById('back').style.display='none';};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works great what if no previous history? +1 page but you are on the last page. Back works but how can i hide `previous` button/image on the last page?

Comment: onclick="history.go(-1);timesClicked++;" then change the if statement to if(history.length===1-timesClicked)

Comment: it doesnt work i added as ` <script>
    if(history.length===1){
    document.getElementById('back').style.display='none';};
    if(history.length===1-timesClicked){
   document.getElementById('prev').style.display='none';};
</script>` on for the button `<img style="width: 150px;" id="prev" onclick="history.go(-1);timesClicked++;" src="go-back-button2.png"/>`

Answer (score 0):

just use history.lenght like:
// add ids on button

```
if (history.length > 1){
 //hide button based on id
}
```